# Problems with ejected Expo app on IOS (React-Native)

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm having troubles with my ejected Expo app for IOS.

Started building the app with Expo, but after some time I needed Bluetooth functionalities, so decided to eject, to use native code. Everything works fine, but when I try to load my app on an IOS-device (after building in xcode), it won't run the way it would like it to.

I would like to try the app, via a hotspot (4G), but it won't start. When there is no Wifi it will start but says 'Connect to Metro to develop Javascript'.

**My question is: Can I make my app into a standalone app, without the Expo server running on a pc on the same wifi network?**